# How to get the height of several containers with the same class

Tags: javascript

I'm currently trying to find out and access the height of several div containers that have the same class "content".

My HTML code Looks like this:

```
 <div class = “main”>
        <div class="item">
          <div class = “content”>
            <p></p>
          </div>
        </div>   
        <div class="item">
          <div class = “content”>
            <p></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class = “content”>
            <p></p>
          </div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

My JavaScript looks like this:

```
let allContents = document.querySelectorAll(".content");

let allItems = document.querySelectorAll(”.item”);

let heightOfContents = allContents.offsetHeight;
```

Unfortunately I have no success with this.

I also tried the following:

```
let heightOfContents = document.querySelector(".content").getBoundingClientRect().height;
```

which didn't work either.

I am expecting to get on the console the heigt of each container and to use them for further calculations.

Would any of you have an idea how this could work?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: `allContents.map(item => item.offsetHeight)`

Comment: Here is working solution - https://codepen.io/Rafi-R/pen/oNJENmm

Answer (score 1):

You attempted to get the height of a single container, try something like this instead:

```
const containers = document.querySelectorAll(".content");
let totalHeight = 0;
containers.forEach((c) => (totalHeight += c.getBoundingClientRect().height));
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), `document.querySelectorAll(".content")` returns a static (not live) NodeList representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors.

You cannot get the `offsetHeight` on a list. You may loop through this node list to get each height for further calculation.

```
const allContents = document.querySelectorAll(".content");
const allItems = document.querySelectorAll(".item");

const contentHeights = [];
allContents.forEach(item => {
    contentHeights.push(item.offsetHeight)
});

const itemHeights = [];
allItems.forEach(item => {
    itemHeights.push(item.offsetHeight)
});
```